# Show that for each divisor d of n there exists exactly one subgroup H of G with |H|=d.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order n. Show that for each divisor d of
> n there exists exactly one subgroup H of G with |H|=d.

I have now thought about the following proof for the given task:

Let $G=\langle a\rangle$, and let $|G|=o(a)=n$ and let $d \mid n$. Then $H_{d}=\left\langle a^{n / d}\right\rangle$ is a subgroup of order d since $o\left(a^{n / d}\right)=d$. Therefore, G has at least one subgroup of order d:

Let H be any subgroup of order d, then H is cyclic ($H=\left\langle a^{k}\right\rangle, 1 \leq k \leq n$). Since $d=o\left(a^{k}\right)=n / \operatorname{gcd}(k, n)$, $\operatorname{gcd}(k, n)=n / d$. $k=\frac{n}{d} t$, with $1 \leq t \leq d$.

Now every element in H is also in $H_{d}$, so that $H \subseteq H_{d}$. This forces $H=\bar{H}_{d}$ since $|H|=d=\left|H_{d}\right|$. Therefore, every subgroup of order d is equal to $H_{d}$, making $H_{d}$ the unique subgroup of order d.

**Can I prove it like this (so I'm not quite sure whether I've really shown everything sufficiently here - especially in the middle part)**

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @ultralegend5385: Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: @Shaun: I didn't even know that this tag existed - thank you :)